# PHP function produces correct values, returns 0

Tags: php, mysql

I have a function that's supposed to run a mysql query and return $output. The variables print properly when I echo them within the function, but if I try to print `$schoolNamesListEngland` in the main code it just displays a 0.

```
while ($preparedStatement->fetch())
{
    echo $id . " " . $name . "<br>";
    $output += "<option value='" . $id . "'>" . $name . "</option>";
}
$output += "</select>";

return $output;
```

Function call:

```
$schoolNamesListEngland = getSchoolList($connection, "England");
```

Comment: Take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php. You want to concatenate, not add.

Comment: Somebody is coming from javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jast replace `$output += "</select>";` with `$output .= "</select>";`